# How do I return data from a custom react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom react hook that is fetching data from an api. I'm getting error: "Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

I don't know if this is due to the structure of my custom hook or how I'm using the hook in the component where it's being called.

Here is my custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

function useFetchNGSData(endpoint) {
    const[data, setData] = useState(null);

    const dateString = () => {
        // MORE CODE
        return date.toString();
    }

    const ngs_username = process.env.REACT_APP_NGS_USERNAME;
    const ngs_password = process.env.REACT_APP_NGS_PASSWORD;
    const ngs_access_token = process.env.REACT_APP_NGS_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    const ngs_secret_key = process.env.REACT_APP_NGS_SECRET_KEY;
    
    const string_to_sign = ngs_username + ngs_password + ngs_access_token + dateString();
    const digest = crypto.createHmac('sha1', ngs_secret_key).update(string_to_sign).digest('base64');
    const authKey = 'NGS ' + ngs_access_token + ':' + digest;
    
    const url = 'https://api.ngs.com';

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authKey;
        axios.get(url + endpoint)
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    },[endpoint]);

    return { data };
}

export default useFetchNGSData;
```

Here's the component that is using the custom hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useFetchNGSData from '../useFetchNGSData';

const Data = (props) => {
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

    const handleGetPlayers = () => {
        teamCollection.forEach(teamId => {      
            setPlayers(useFetchNGSData('/league/roster/current?teamId=5100')
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            // ... handleGetPlayers
        </div>
    );
}

export default Data;
```

I know I'm omitting a lot of code but hopefully this is enough to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the hook out of the event handler, and in to the body of the component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useFetchNGSData from '../useFetchNGSData';

const Data = (props) => {
    const { data: players } = useFetchNGSData('/league/roster/current?teamId=5100')
    return (
        <div>
            // ... handleGetPlayers
        </div>
    );
}

export default Data;
```

But really, you don't need to use setPlayers here. You already have that data in your returned values from your custom hook.

Comment: My setPlayers is actually in a loop - I've updated the code above - each time thru a new team is added to the teamCollection.  Does this change the way useFetchNGSData is called?

Comment: No, the hook has to always be called directly in the render body of the component. But if you need to grab a new value from the hook for each iteration, based on the previous set operation, you'll need to do a few things to make that work. Probably the most straightforward way to to extract a "getter" function from the hook, and have the hook use that getter function, and then import both the hook and the getter. Then you can call the getter in your loop. You may alternatively want to consider exposing a setter from your hook which would accept an array and do the iteration within the hook.

Comment: Based on your snippet - I'd guess you have a lot of async things to work out as well.

Comment: I think this is a bit above my understanding. Are you able to provide an example?